# zend error while assigning view

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-view

So installed the latest 2.0 version of Zend. I am having trouble in defining the view in controller and then displaying. 
If I create a new ViewModel and return it, it works fine. For example.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new ViewModel();
    }

$this->view->hello="hey";
$this->view->test="there";
return $this->view;
```

But I never had to do this in Zend 1.8 or before.
Without creating a new model, it gives me the following error:

```
Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in /path-to-controller-file.php
```

Do I Have to set it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZF2 is vastly different from the previous versions of Zend Framework, so you'll probably run into a few issues like this.

The error you are encountering is because `$this->view` would be `null` without the `new ViewModel()` and therefore setting further variables on a null is triggering that error. From my understanding of ZF2 - the view and controller have been purposely separated.

Typically in ZF2 you return data from an action doing:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->hello = 'hey';

return $viewModel;
```

You can also return an array if I remember correctly:

```
return array('hello' => 'hey');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend @DrBezas answer:

While it is true that you could return an array from your controllers actions, it is certainly not the suggested route. Always at least return an instanceof ViewModel. Returning an array only will lead into some performance issued [as explained in my blog](http://samminds.com/2012/11/zf2-performance-quicktipp-1-viewmodels/).

The best approach would be to always return a fully qualified ViewModel like

```
public function someAction() 
{
    $viewModel = new ViewMode();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('MODULE / CONTROLLER / ACTION');

    // more controller logic

    return $viewModel->setVariables(array(
         //key-value-paired view variables
    ));
}
```